# laravel 5.7 route collection error, notfoundhttpexception how can i solve it?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid, laravel-5.7

I am sending id from angularjs to get id related specific record, this is my angularjs code.

```
$http.post("getSingleRecord",{"id": id})
.success(function(response){
 console.log(response);
});
```

And in my laravel controller I have received data like this. And I have defined my router in framework/src/illuminate/routing/router.php. But I am receiving this error NotFoundHttpException in Routing/RouteCollection.php at line 179. In web.php I have just returned Auth::routes(); and all my routes are working but only this one is not working

```
$this->post("/getSingleRecord/{id}","controller@getRecord");
```

And ofcourse in my controller method i-e; getRecord, I have received id like this, but I am not getting any id, any help would be appreciated, Thanks

```
$id = $request->route('id'); //laravel 5.7
print_r($id); //just want to see the id here
exit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Laravel route is expecting a parameter in the url, but you're sending it in the POST data.

Try this:

```
$http.post(`getSingleRecord/${id}`,{})
```